# Pine Script V5 issue

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In Pine Script V5, how can I know if the current bar is the last bar for that trading day, as I want to exit my entire position before the end of that trading day.

`ta.change(time("D"))` can know the first bar of the next trading day, but how can I know the last bar of the current trading day?

Comment: please change you title of the script, to be more cleare what you were trying to archive. We all know this is about Pine, cause you tagged it that way. To edit your post you can press the [Edit Button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77220926/edit).

Answer (score 0):

From Strategy library
https://www.tradingview.com/v/mCOgJC67/

```
// @function             A wrapper of the `strategy.close()` built-in which closes the position matching the `entryId` on the close of the last bar of the trading session. 
// @param entryId        (series string) A required parameter. The order identifier. It is possible to close an order by referencing its identifier.
// @param comment        (series string) Optional. Additional notes on the order.
// @param alertMessage   (series string) An optional parameter which replaces the {{strategy.order.alert_message}} placeholder when it is used in the "Create Alert" dialog box's "Message" field.
// @returns              (void) Closes `entryId` on the `close` of the last bar of the trading session, instead of the `open` of the next session. 
export closeAtEndOfSession(series string entryId, series string comment = na, series string alertMessage = na) =>
    if session.islastbar and barstate.isconfirmed
        strategy.close(entryId, comment, alert_message = alertMessage, immediately = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to get what you want.
A few examples...

```
session.islastbar   // true on last bar of session
time_close("1D")    // Unix time of todays close
ta.barssince(session.isfirstbar) + 1    // closing bar of previous session
```

the following I would recommend when trying to exit on the last bar...

```
if time_close == time_close("1D")
    ... (your exit code)
```

it compares the closing time of the most right bar with the closing time of the day.

when you trying to build a strategy for backtesting,
then keep in mind this will execute your order after the bar has finished,
so you need to prepare for that.

```
if time_close == time_close("1D") - (timeframe.in_seconds() * 1000)
    ... (your exit code for previous calculated exit)
```